# "if" statement not moving to the "else" clause

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, random

I'm writing a function for a small game in which a list of jobs is populated each turn. The jobs themselves are objects with a route, time, and pay attribute.

I want the list to be 5 items total and randomly populated by picking from a list of routes and pay grades.

I have a for loop to iterate 5 times, and I'm wanting the pay grade selected to be 5 only if a certain two routes are selected. Otherwise, the pay grades will be a random number between 1 and 4.

When I set the pay grade to 5 in the IF clause, it never makes it to the else clause even if the conditions of the IF are not true. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
for pick in range(5):
    job = random.choice(random_routes)
    if job == 'Military Base' or 'Raiders':
        pay_key = 5
    else:
        pay_key = random.randint(1, 4)
    pay = pay_grades[pay_key]

    job_postings.append(Job(job, routes[job], pay))
```

printing the first index attributes from the new job_postings list always returns level 5 pay numbers even if the route picked was not Military Base or Raiders.

Here are the route and pay dictionaries:

```
routes = {'Boneyard': 5, 'Brotherhood': 6, 'Cathedral': 6, 'Junktown': 4,
          'Military Base': 14, 'Necropolis': 5, 'Raiders': 10, 'Shady Sands': 11}

pay_grades = {
    1: random.randrange(200, 401, 50),
    2: random.randrange(300, 501, 50),
    3: random.randrange(400, 601, 50),
    4: random.randrange(500, 701, 50),
    5: random.randrange(900, 1600, 50),
}
```

Comment: `if job == 'Military Base' or 'Raiders':` should probably be `if job == 'Military Base' or job == 'Raiders':`.

Comment: `job == 'Military Base' or 'Raiders'` will always be true, because `'Raiders'` is a truthy value and you've `or`ed it with `job == 'Military Base'`.

Comment: With your current if-clause, the second half after the `or`, `'Raiders'` always evaluates to `True` (since a non-empty string is always `True` in Python), and thus the `else` will never be entered.

Comment: @Samwise wow thanks, should've seen that

Comment: Since this question is so common it would be nice to know what is the canonical answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes it does, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies on this line:

```
if job == 'Military Base' or 'Raiders':
```

The `==` operator takes precedence over the `or` operator, which means it's evaluating the same as,

```
if (job == 'Military Base') or ('Raiders'):
```

Any non-empty string evaluates to true (compare `not ''` and `not 'abc'` in the REPL) and therefore `'Raiders'` and this entire conditional expression will always evaluate to true.

What you actually seem to want is,

```
if job == 'Military Base' or job == 'Raiders':
```

Comment: Another, possibly preferable approach would be `if job in ( 'Military Base', 'Raiders'):` The advantage is that this scales out nicely as we add options, and it allows you to make the choices more dynamic (they are no longer hard-coded, so we can pass them around, etc)

Comment: And if we talk about performance we use a set: `if job in {'Military Base', 'Raiders'}:`. But of course with just two entries that's not important.

Answer (score 0):

when you say

```
    if job == 'Military Base' or 'Raiders':
```

second condition means: if 'Raiders' == True and it does not mean Raiders equals 'Military Base'.

corrected:
if job == 'Military Base' or job == 'Raiders':